# how to avoid resizing texture in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, textures, skaction

I am adding the spritenode to the scene, the size is given.

But when I change the texture of the spritenode, the size automatically changes to the original size of the image(png) of the texture.

How can I avoid this?

My code:

```
var bomba = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bomba2") 
var actionbomba = SKAction()
bomba.size = CGSizeMake(frame2.size.width/18, frame2.size.width/18)   
let bomba3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bomba3.png")
actionbomba.addObject(SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(0, frame.size.height/2.65), duration: beweegsnelheid))
actionbomba.addObject(SKAction.setTexture(bomba3,resize: false))         

addChild(bomba)
bomba.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence(actionbomba), count: -1))
```

Comment: why is your action being repeated -1 times

Comment: because the sprite keeps moving

Comment: what is beweegsnelheid?

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the size explicitly.  From your information sprite kit will not automatically find the scale factor for each texture and scale it.

Instead, you set the scale factor of the node and each texture will have that scale applied to it.

```
[playernode setScale: x];
```

Something like this.  You only have to set it when you create the node and each texture will be the size you would expect, given that your textures are the same size.

I use this method for all of my nodes that are animated with multiple textures and it works every time.

Comment: But the size need to be frame.size.width/18. I can't achieve this with your solution because of the different screen ratios. Any other solution?

Comment: What is wrong with doing basic math to calculate what your x should be based on screen size?

Comment: You have access to the size of your sprite.  You have access to the desired size of your sprite (frame size/18).  There should be nothing you are missing to find what the scale factor should be (x).